# How do I get multiple VLOOKUP from another sheet to the same cell inside an ARRAYFORMULA?

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

Just to warn that I am quite new to Google Sheet (and Excel) programming, but experienced otherwise (30+ years programming on and off and this is my first question online).

I use Google Sheet to keep tabs on student lockers and have a sheet with lockers that can be borrowed by our students in a list like this (many more columns but not used here):
"LockerID" "Location" "LockerInformation" "UserID"

And then I have wanted to view a class with a list of students and see what they have borrowed like this:
"UserID" "UserName" "LockerID (LockerLocation)"

Since they can borrow multiple lockers I can't use a simple `VLOOKUP` and I would like the result like this:
"ghdsy45" "Johan Andersson" "45 (House-1), 78 (House-4)"

My code works great (have LockerID and LockerLocation on separate columns so far) on a single row but when I tried to convert it to an `ARRAYFORMULA` I can't get it working, even after many hours trying.

Any help from an experienced programmer would be much appreciated.

It feels so simple but I have tried everything I have found from others trying to do something similar but none have done all parts together (that I have found).

```
={"Borrowed";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A4:A),Join(", ",IFERROR(QUERY('ItemList'!A:M,"select A where M='"&A4:A&"'",1)),""),""))}
```

Expected to get `M=A4:A` to check for each row but all rows just check against `A4`. So all rows just show what the first UserID has borrowed.

edit: Want to clarify that it is with around 2000 lockers and 1500 students, so a too complex solution will give too long update times and render it unusable.

Comment: I have made a sample sheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n94p4SOnBkl45OzB8XUNh2F75KuunKLR1Q5zGelSyUM/edit?usp=sharing
Vill add more when I have time to show more of what I have tried.

Comment: is the D column of Borrowed sheet your desired output?

Comment: Prefered output would be LockerID (Location), LockerID (Location)

Answer (score 0):

cell **А1**:

```
={"UserID", "Name"; FILTER({Users!A2:A, Users!C2:C}, Users!B2:B="B2")}
```

cell **C1**:

```
={"Lockers"; ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(IF(ISNUMBER(SPLIT(D2:D, " ")), 
 SPLIT(D2:D, " "), )), "\d+"))), , 999^99))), " ", " - "))}
```

cell **D1**:

```
={"Lockers per Houses"; ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, 
 {ARRAY_CONSTRAIN((QUERY({LockerList!A2:A&"♦"&LockerList!B2:B, LockerList!B2:D}, 
 "select Col4,count(Col4) where Col3 is not null group by Col4 pivot Col1")), 999^99, 1), 
 SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(ISNUMBER(QUERY({LockerList!A2:A&"♦"&LockerList!B2:B, LockerList!B2:D}, 
 "select Col4,count(Col4) where Col3 is not null group by Col4 pivot Col1")), 
 ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY({LockerList!A2:A&"♦"&LockerList!B2:B, LockerList!B2:D}, 
 "select Col4,count(Col4) where Col3 is not null group by Col4 pivot Col1"), 1, 999^99), ))
 , , 999^99))), " ", ", "), "♦", " ")}, 2, 0)))}
```

[image: 0]

### [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RCW3bUyhd8XW95yunntPc8KoQUtSdlzoAu1mmu6JKU0/edit#gid=512168212)

Comment: Works like a charm!

Thank you VERY much! You have saved me hours upon hours trying to sole if my self. Will analyze what you have done so I can learn how it realy works. So once again, thank you very much!

I actually want it like 7 (House-1), 8 (House-2) but if I can't solve that by my self now I don't deserve to have it like that :)

Comment: Unfortunatly it takes almost one minute (57s) to update when I change what class to view,  6-32 students, with 2000 lockers in the list. :(
So, it was a solution that worked but is not usable for me then.

Comment: My original solution with one formula per cell to get LockerIDs tock around 1s with:
=IF(A4<>"",JOIN(" - ",IFERROR(FILTER(LockerList!A:A,'LockerList!D:D=A4),"")),"")

And another column with the Location doing the same. Not at all as nice with the reults in the same cell and with an ARRAYFORMULA.

The main reason I want all the formula in one cell is that I want to easy change the header row to show different statistics. But looks like I have to populate every cell with a formula via a script instead.

Comment: =IF(A3<>"",JOIN(", ",IFERROR(FILTER(LockerList!A:A&" ("&LockerList!B:B&")",LockerList!D:D=A3),"")),"")
 this actually gives me everything I want, except I have to fill in in every cell. But almost instantly instead of a minute to update.

Comment: you could make it faster if you replace all ranges with indirect like: `INDIRECT("LockerList!A2:A"&COUNTA(LockerList!A2:A)+1)`